# Compatibilidade de Assembly e arquiteturas

Tags: assembly, x86, x64, arquitetura-computadores

Eu não tenho experiência nenhuma com a linguagem de baixo nível Assembly.

O que é necessário para obter o máximo de *cross platform* com essa linguagem?

Digo, se me focar apenas na AMD64 (x86-64) obterei compatibilidade com todos os computadores atuais?

Comment: Obrigado,mas não entendi onde estou incitando opinião.Eu não entendo de assembly.Gostaria apenas saber sua capacidade de cross platform.

Comment: @Segio Não entendo de Assembly, mas ele só está perguntando sobre compatibilidade mesmo. Não é preciso fechar a pergunta.

Comment: @Andrey e Weslley, ok. Retirei o voto para fechar.

Comment: Desculpem minha inexperiência no stack,espero que com a ultima edição tenha evidenciado minha real duvida.

Comment: Sim, melhorou e estou respondendo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cada arquitetura de processador tem sua própria linguagem Assembly, é assim desde o início dos computadores modernos na década de 40. A única forma de explorar melhor uma arquitetura é criando uma forma de usá-la de uma forma bem específica. Assembly não é *cross platform* por definição. Se isto for necessário, use C.

Bom, na verdade cada arquitetura tem um código de máquina diferente, o que faz com que o Assembly seja diferente. É possível ter sintaxes diferentes para a mesma arquitetura.

Atualmente existem centenas ou até mesmo milhares de arquiteturas em uso. Claro que ninguém aprende todos. O mais comum é aprender só um ou dois, quem sabe três.

Aprender várias linguagens Assembly não é difícil. Difícil é ser muito bom em várias. E não há muito espaço no mercado para quem não é muito bom. Lembremos que hoje quase não se usa mais Assembly em qualquer tarefa.

E mesmo que se foque em uma arquitetura pode ser que precise aprender sintaxes diferentes de Assembly. Há *assemblers* que preferem uma sintaxe diferente para fazer a mesma coisa. Para x86 há a [sintaxe Intel e a sintaxe AT&T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax). Mas a sintaxe é a menor das preocupações.

As arquiteturas mais utilizadas hoje são disparadamente o x86_64 (**maioria** dos *desktops*) e o ARM (**maioria** dos *mobiles*). De uma certa forma o segundo até já ultrapassou o primeiro.

Todas as outras arquiteturas somadas não chegam perto destas duas. Mas algumas podem ser mais importantes para Assembly. Arquiteturas de dispositivos embarcados, que normalmente não são muito usados, ainda continuam usando Assembly como linguagem principal. Isto tem mudado bastante. Cada vez mais se usa C ou C++ mesmo nestes casos mas o Assembly é comum.

A linguagem Assembly tem vínculo absoluto com o processador e nada mais. Sistemas operacionais não afetam o Assembly em si. Claro que talvez você tenha que lidar com especificardes deles mas por outros motivos e não pela linguagem. Exemplo:

- Se você não estiver usando um *assembler* (duvido) terá que saber o formato do arquivo executável do sistema operacional.
- Acessar a API (processos, arquivos, GUI, etc.) do sistema operacional é sempre feita de forma específica para ele mas não pertence à linguagem.

Note que se você não estiver escrevendo um *backend* de um compilador, saber só o Assembly é a ponta do *iceberg*. Mesmo neste caso, o Assembly é apenas um parte do conhecimento necessário.

Aprender Assembly é muito útil para entender o funcionamento do computador, para ter um *hobby* mas hoje sua utilização prática reduziu enormemente. Raramente se usa mesmo para produzir sistemas operacionais ou *drivers*. Fora compiladores/[JITters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) (mesmo assim, não todos os tipos), *bootstrap* e alguma arquitetura que não possua outra linguagem, Assembly é absolutamente desnecessário.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Assembly/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado,abriu horizontes.