# Como um computador entende o código binário?

Tags: assembly, binary

Como um computador entende o código binário? Como o código binário foi criado e quem a criou?

Comment: Gostei da pergunta ela bem interessante, mas acho que será fechada por ser ampla demais, a não ser que exista uma resposta que esclareça um pouco, nesse caso eu gostaria de ver uma resposta + 1 ;)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## Parte concreta

Como o nome diz o binário é só uma sequência de bits, ou seja, algum indicador de estado ligado ou desligado. No momento da sua execução são apenas pulsos elétricos de baixa e alta tensão (alta é modo de dizer, na verdade é bem baixa, só é um pouco mais alta, e baixa é quase zero).

Tudo isso vai passando por [portas lógicas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate) (são equivalentes eletrônicos de [relés](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rel%C3%A9)) que fazem alguma operação, em geral:

- invertendo o sinal do 0 ou 1 (`not`),
- mantendo o estado (`buffer`),
- resultando em 1 quando pelo menos um de dois sinais são um (`or`),
- ou em 1 se os dois sinais são 1 (`and`),
- além de algumas variações dessas.

Conforme os bits vão passando vão excitando esses "relés" de acordo com as portas lógicas e vão determinando para que caminho vão estes e outros bits. Decisões no processador são as portas se abrindo ou fechando de acordo com os pulsos elétricos (dados, informações) vão passando pelas portas.

Tudo que o processador sabe fazer é isso. Um conjunto de portas interligadas em ordem específica vai produzindo ações específicas.

Pense nas portas como instruções bem simples (mas bem concretas) que colocadas em determinada ordem formam um programa, um algoritmo, para fazer as coisas mais básicas (uma adição, que nem é a mais simples de programar, mas a mais simples de você entender), até alguma bem complexa em processadores modernos ou de uso mais específico (uma criptografia ou vetorização, por exemplo). Isso varia de acordo com a arquitetura (veja mais abaixo).

O processador possui um [conjunto de instruções](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set).

Os bits passam por essas portas uma vez por ciclo medindo em [Hertz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz). Em um processador de 3.0Ghz eles passam 3 bilhões de vezes por segundo (uma lâmpada costuma "piscar" 60 vezes por segundo). Algumas instruções precisam passar várias vezes para executarem por completo. Mesmo uma adição não pode ser realizada em uma única passagem (ciclo).

Um processador é uma enorme [máquina de estados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Os processadores modernos possuem bilhões de [transistores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor) (portas lógicas).

Esquema exemplo de portas (obviamente isto é uma representação para um humano entender melhor):

[image: ALU gates]

## Parte abstrata

Então todo processador no fundo tem "programas" dentro deles feitos com mecanismos elétricos que em alguns casos são chamados de [*microcode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode). Parte do que tem ali é para controlar como esses programas devem funcionar. Uma parte é fazer um conteúdo da memória ir pra dentro dele, entender do que se trata e fazer alguma coisa. Algum conteúdo é o tal código binário. Então alguns bits entram em um lugar específico e acionam uma parte do processador que deve fazer algo.

Já teve época que se programava o hardware mesmo, ou seja, ia organizando portas ou conjuntos prontos de portas para fazer o que se desejava. Acontecia nos anos 40 quando a computação moderna começou, e acontecia bastante até os anos 70, agora acontece pouco, mas ainda acontece em nichos.

A criação de um processador, simplificadamente, é um misto de achar e manipular os materiais certos para dar as propriedades que se deseja (velocidade, dissipação, etc.) e criar "programas" dentro deles que executarão as coisas mais básicas.

Alguns bits indicam que o processador deverá passar o controle para o "programinha interno" que faz uma adição, por exemplo. Os bits seguintes são os valores que serão usados para somar (simplificadamente são algumas portas `or` com uma reentrância para cuidar do "vai um") e o resultado é colocado em uma área do processador para outra instrução fazer alguma outra operação, possivelmente enviar para a memória.

Algumas arquiteturas possuem instruções de tamanho variável (de 4 à 120 bits no Intel, por exemplo) tipicamente em [CISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computing), em outras o tamanho da instrução é sempre o mesmo não importando qual seja ela (tamanho da palavra, 32 ou 64 bits, no ARM), tipicamente em [RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing).

Simplificadamente, o primeiro tem a vantagem de economia de espaço, o segundo tem a vantagem de performance e eficiência, ainda que existam técnicas para compensar um ou outro, portanto é mais complexo e hoje uma ajuda a outra ir melhorando.

Agora, como ele pega esses bits e sabe o que fazer? Tem "programinhas" controlando isso. Isso é o [ciclo de instrução](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_cycle) ([carrega, decodifica e executa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit#Operation)). Veja [explicação um pouco mais detalhada](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Computer_Components,_The_Stored_Program_Concept_and_the_Internet/Machine_Level_Architecture/The_Fetch%E2%80%93Execute_cycle_and_the_role_of_registers_within_it). Da Wikipedia (típico em CISC, em RISC as instruções possuem um ciclo mais simples):

1. Cálculo do endereço de memória que contém a instrução
2. Busca da instrução
3. Decodificação da instrução
4. Cálculo do endereço dos operandos
5. Busca do operando (Operand Fetch)
6. Execução da operação
7. Armazenamento do resultado em um endereço de memória ou registrador

Uma série de controles específicos são usados para fazer tudo isso funcionar, tipicamente: [PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter), [MAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address_register), [MDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_data_register), [IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_register), [CU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_unit), [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit), [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit), só pra ficar nos básicos. Processadores modernos e de uso geral tem partes que fazem muito mais que isso para otimizar operações e fornecer outras funcionalidades.

Em processadores mais gerais existem algumas partes mais específicas para ajudar o sistema operacional funcionar, tais como controle de processos, memória, interrupções (sinalização), proteção, etc. Algumas mais específicas para certos tipos de aplicação, principalmente em processadores mais modernos e poderosos, um exemplo é a virtualização.

[image: Algoritmo de execução de uma instrução]

Fico por aqui porque a pergunta é um pouco ampla e quase fora de escopo (mas longe de ser passível de ser fechada).

Obviamente fiz algumas simplificações, não leve tudo ao pé da letra e nem falei da comunicação do processador com a memória. Pode perguntar coisas mais específicas para o desenvolvedor entender o que está fazendo.

Aliás, é interessante ver como uma máquina virtual de linguagem funciona: [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101), [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), [Parrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrot_virtual_machine), [NekoVM](http://nekovm.org/) e específicas de linguagens como [Lua](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/%7Eroberto/talks/lua-ll3.pdf), PHP, Pyhton, Harbour, etc., porque elas simulam um processador em toda essa parte abstrata (nas interpretadas em um enorme `switch-case` :) ).

Leitura complementar:

- [Todo processador utiliza o mesmo conjunto de instruções?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109886/101)
- [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101)
- [Como funciona e qual é a síntaxe do código de máquina?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117796/101)
- [Compatibilidade de Assembly e arquiteturas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22854/101)

[Quer brincar de programação binária?](http://s2js.com/altair/sim.html).

[Brinque com isto](http://visual6502.org/JSSim/index.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Estava torcendo para vc responder :D

Comment: Eu não entendo muito bem, mas gostaria de te perguntar: esta frase está certa "resultando em **1** quando pelo menos dois sinais são **um** (or) ou em **1** se os dois sinais são **1** (and)"?

Comment: @jbueno fiz para ver se vocês estavam atentos :D Obrigado.

Comment: Ótima resposta. Resumiu arquitetura de processadores em poucas linhas.

Comment: "Já teve época que se programava o hardware mesmo, ou seja, ia organizando portas ou conjuntos prontos de portas para fazer o que se desejava", me lembrei do Fortran, onde a programação era feita com cartões perfurados.

Comment: @JulioBorges Na verdade não há essa relação direta. Eu programei em Fortran há muito tempo sem cartão perfurado. E já vi muitas linguagens usando cartão perfurado. De qualquer forma o que eu falei é mais embaixo ainda, falo dos *chips* ou transistores (ou válvulas).

Comment: @bigown, Pois eh, é incrível como a tecnologia evolui constantemente, fico impressionado com tudo isso.

Comment: Na verdade é só uma ilustração pra quem nunca viu um esquema de portas lógicas, sem nenhuma intenção que a pessoa vá analisar o que aquilo faz. Não é intenção da resposta se aprofundar no funcionamento do hardware, a primeira parte é só para não deixar a pessoa no vácuo. Você se interessou por isso porque já conhece, mas a intenção era focar na decodificação da instrução e sua execução. Mas acho que ainda vou melhorá-la, não esperava que teria tanta aceitação.

Comment: Gostei muito da resposta, mas me surgiu uma dúvida sobre o ultimo parágrafo. Em que você fala "elas simulam um processador em toda a parte abstrata (nas interpretadas em um enorme switch-case)". Como isso funciona? Existe alguma pergunta sobre isso aqui no SOpt?

Comment: @Francisco que eu saiba não tem nada no site não, Não sei se entendi o que quer saber que funciona, mas de qq forma deve ser longa pra comentar aqui.

Answer (score 14):

Complementando o assunto,

Num resumo geral, para quem está boiando, a lógica do código binário é

0 -> desligado

1 -> ligado.

## Computação moderna

Os primeiros "computadores modernos" organizavam dados em "[cartões de furos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card)". Normalmente quem frequentou aulas básicas de informática, aprende sobre o assunto. Os cartões de furos foram criados em 1832 e mais tarde, no início do século 19 foi aprimorado por uma empresa que hoje conhecemos como [IBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM).

Em 1946 surgiram as [células de memória](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_cell_(binary)). Compostas por circuitos integrados, formados por transistores e capacitores. Isso originou a memória RAM (DRAM, SRAM) e diversos outros dispositivos como os [Flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Origens

A criação do código binário moderno é atribuída a [Gottfried Leibniz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottfried_Wilhelm_Leibniz).

A inspiração dele foi o [I CHING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Ching) chinês. Toda a criação do código é baseada nos diagramas do mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]