# A primeira linguagem de programação

Tags: assembly, compiladores, design-de-linguagem, teoria-da-computação

Até a época em que os computadores eram puramente **mecânicos** e eram programados por **cartões perfurados** eu entendo como funciona. Depois, quando surgiram os primeiros computadores "digitais" operados com válvulas e relés fica mais complicado de compreender como eram feitas as programações. Imagino que deveria haver algo semelhante a um compartimento com uma matriz de relés (semelhante aos cartões perfurados) pré programada, que continha um programa fixo e único a ser executado pela máquina. Quando fosse preciso trocar o programa, os programadores apenas rearranjavam as válvulas e a máquina continuava a trabalhar.

Como surgiu essa noção que temos de programação hoje que o programador digita códigos em um editor de texto e compila. Eu não consigo imaginar como chegou a esse ponto. Por exemplo o assembly, ele é apenas traduzido de textos para binário pelo assembler, mas poxa, seria preciso ter outra linguagem de programação para se criar o assembler.

Suponha que só existam os computadores controlados por relés e válvulas. Como que alguém conseguiria escrever um código em assembly sendo que não existia editor de textos nem nada.

O resultado de uma montagem é outro arquivo no formato texto com 0's e 1's apenas? Ou são impulsos elétricos enviados para a máquina valvulada.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua dúvida, vc precisa ser mais especifico a isso. Eu sugeria vc que começasse pelas [gerações de computadores](http://producao.virtual.ufpb.br/books/camyle/introducao-a-computacao-livro/livro/livro.chunked/ch01s02.html), para vc etender como eles funcionam, detalhe, o conceito de computador digital (código binario) surgiu com o transistor, foi aí que surgiu o código de maquina que é a linguagem binária e a base da computação **digital**.

Comment: Eu entendi perfeitamente, é um pergunta interessante, mas não para o formato do site, vai acabar por gerar respostas bem amplas. Eu ainda fui ler a resposta a ver se dava para salvar, e sinceramente acho que não. dei +1 mas pus para fechar.

Comment: Talvez aprender um pouco de eletrônica digital ajude. Os desdobramentos todos na parte do software foram maneiras de se facilitar a vida apenas.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho na verdade transistores vieram bem depois

Comment: Acho que vai depender do que você aceitaria como sendo uma linguagem. Exemplo, um switch é uma linguagem. Diz apenas ON/OFF. Observe nas paredes da sua casa, tem vários deles e você usa todos os dias para ligar e desligar lâmpadas. Agora, tente obervar de outro ângulo. Pense em como poderia melhorar esse mecanismo tão simples. A maioria diria que não tem o que melhorar ou que não tem o que fazer. Uns poucos diriam "acho que posso adicionar uma engrenagem ou uma estrutura com slider para deslizar/girar sob um circuito de resistores e assim controlar os níveis de energia".

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## TL;DR

Algumas afirmações na pergunta usam premissas contemporâneas. Tem que abandonar tudo isso para entender o funcionamento dos computadores "antigos". E duvido que algo sucinto vá dar uma ideia boa de como os computadores funcionavam. Na verdade isso só acontecerá mais concretamente com muito estudo. É muita variação.

0s e 1s podem ser armazenados e processados de diversas formas. Sua entrada e saída também.

> seria preciso ter outra linguagem de programação para se criar o *assembler*

Não precisa. Você pode fazer na mão. Não é uma tarefa agradável para um ser humano, mas era o que tinha. E isso, acho eu que, decifra muito da dúvida.

Na premissa da pergunta não houve uma primeira linguagem de programação em computadores. Ela só existia no papel. Alguém escrevia o que o programa deveria executar, transformava ali mesmo em códigos numéricos e depois eram convertidos para binário, tudo na mão, exatamente como o computador faz, exceto a conversão para binário porque internamente tudo já é binário mesmo. Internamente a linguagem era código binário.

Então o Assembly, ou uma forma rudimentar dele, existia só no papel. O montador era humano. O montador automatizado surgiu depois, já que não fazia sentido não usar o computador para automatizar um monte de problema, mas não automatizar o seu próprio problema.

As linguagens de alto nível nasceram assim também. Cansaram de escrever algo compreensível e depois também escrever o Assembly para executar aquilo.

> o resultado de uma montagem é outro arquivo no formato texto com 0's e 1's apenas?

De certa forma podemos dizer que sim, mas não é uma definição precisa.

> Ou são impulsos elétricos enviados para a máquina valvulada.

Tudo em computadores são pulsos elétricos. Mas não é fácil um ser humano gerar esses pulsos por conta própria, então um dispositivo eletromecânico é usado para ser gerado. Chaves são usadas para gerar isso. Até hoje usamos chaves para entrar esses dados. Em inglês chave é *key*, que nós chamamos de tecla. Então um painel de chaves é um *keyboard*, que chamamos de teclado. Essas chaves são organizadas de forma mais fácil para nós usarmos do que eram as chaves nos primórdios.

Os códigos binários eram introduzidos por chaves mecânicas de liga e desliga. Sim, entrava bit por bit.

[image: Painel]

## Introdução

Computadores digitais, ou seja, eletrônicos baseados em 0 e 1 foram criados na década de 30/40. Mais ou menos junto com os [computadores programáveis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z3_(computer)), ou seja, era uma [máquina universal de Turing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101). Pelo menos é o que a história conta. Sempre há quem possa dizer que aconteceu um pouco diferente da história oficial.

[image: Z3]

Inicialmente toda informação era armazenada em uma [forma rudimentar de memória](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams_tube) ([outro exemplo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_line_memory) e [a mais usada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic-core_memory) por muito tempo). Na verdade cada computador tentava uma nova forma um pouco diferente ou um caminho bem diferente, até que uma forma acabou predominando. Mas a memória como conhecemos hoje só surgiu nos anos 70.

Há disputa sobre qual foi o primeiro computador. Por muito tempo o ENIAC foi considerado oficialmente. Mesmo que não seja verdade é importante para entender a evolução. O [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC) tem muitos detalhes que ajudam entender seu funcionamento.

O problema da pergunta é que parece que houve um evento único que estruturou tudo. Na verdade houve muita experimentação, nem todas ficaram tão famosas. Diversos caminhos foram percorridos.

O [Mark I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_Mark_I) (uma das variações) foi um computador importante criado pelo [John Von Newmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann), creditado como o criador da [arquitetura básica dos computadores "modernos"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture). [Outra variação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_Mark_1) também é importante a evolução. Se quiser detalhes mesmo siga os *links*. É difícil entender tudo sem pegar todos os detalhes.

Há uma [lista de computadores que iniciaram a história](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_computing_hardware#Early_digital_computer_characteristics) e que, via de regra, eram [programados na mão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_computing_hardware#Early_digital_computer_characteristics).

Esqueça essa ideia de arquivos, de textos. Era binário mesmo. Pense concretamente.

## Como funcionava

Até houve algum ponto que alguém "programou" o computador rearranjando válvulas. Mas isso não pode ser considerado programação como conhecemos hoje. Rapidamente se percebeu que se precisava de uma forma mais volátil. Precisava que o programa fosse entrado de alguma forma (e até poderia ainda ser cartão perfurado), armazenado e fosse seguido conforme ditava a [teoria de Alan Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine).

Deve imaginar que não havia muito espaço para erro. O programador tinha que ter certeza que seu código não tinha erros. Todos precisavam ser verificados no olho. Claro que naquela época só tinha gente boa trabalhando com isso, eram cuidadosos porque sabiam que não podiam errar, e dominavam todo o processo, afinal eles tinham inventado tudo, e, é claro, só faziam coisas muito simples, para os padrões atuais.

[image: Entrada de dados]

A entrada de dados nada tem a ver com a programação em si. Assim como hoje, programas são dados com um propósito especial. Então se estava entrando com números para calcular ou números que instruíam o computador sobre o que fazer, pouco importava, assim como hoje se você está usando o teclado para mandar uma mensagem ou para criar um programa.

Um dos problemas de ficar mexendo nas chaves é que no momento que ia colocar outro programa, o atual era perdido, obviamente. Aí começaram usar cartões perfurados para os programas (ou fitas de papel). Os cartões eram perfurados de acordo com os bits que haviam sido programados previamente no papel. Então nunca se perdia (a não ser por deterioração do material, mas ele podia ser reproduzido).

[image: Cartão com código binário]

Claro que o cartão era só usado com meio de entrada mesmo. Ele modificava chaves conforme tinha furo ou não. O processo mecânico específico mudava mas o conceito e funcionamento básico era o mesmo.

Note que isso não importa muito. As abstrações criadas é que permitiram a produtividade dos programadores. Por isso as linguagens de maior nível foram sendo criadas. Elas foram conveniências para o humano.

Também precisava de produtividade na entrada de dados. O ganho não é tão grande, mas importante. Assim como tinham teclados para perfurar os cartões, pelo menos em versões mais modernas dos perfuradores, perceberam que poderiam fazer o teclado já mudar as chaves de programação. Claro que já não eram mais mecânicas, pelo menos não puramente.

Cartões perfurados eram usados em computadores mecânicos para entrada de dados puros, não de programas que não existiam.

[image: Entrada moderna]

A imagem abaixo começa mostrar o computador como conhecemos hoje. Isso já era meio da década de 60. Ali havia a entrada por teclado, a saída por impressora ou vídeo, armazenamento por meio magnético (que já está se tornando obsoleto), ainda sequencial, embora talvez tenha um meio randômico em algum lugar não visível. Tinha pouco porque era muito caro.

[image: Computador "moderno"]

Veja como o que é considerado o primeiro micro-computador em 1975 era tão simples que funcionava como os primeiros computadores modernos da década de 40. Ele podia ter um teclado opcional, não sei se logo na primeira versão.

[image: Altair]

[Veja o simulador dele](http://s2js.com/altair/sim.html). Tente programar.

## A primeira linguagem

No sentido da pergunta acredito que o [código binário é a primeira linguagem de programação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code). Ainda que seja altamente provável que existia algo mais abstrato antes.

[image: Código binário]

Não tenho evidências, mas é possível que pelo menos uma forma de Assembly tenha sido usado como primeira linguagem desses computadores modernos, mas não usada em computadores, só no papel. Se for considerar o que foi feito em papel para construir máquinas computacionais, então tem que ver o que a [Ada Lovelace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace) usou, a Note G, conforme mostrado abaixo.

[image: Note G]

As linguagens de alto nível foram criadas inicialmente para dar mais poder cognitivo aos programadores. Mas também foi uma forma de não depender das instruções específicas de um computador e poder ser entendido por qualquer computador, dado uma transformação, manual ou não (naquele momento já se usava montadores e a [criação de um compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101) foi o passo natural).

## Conclusão

Tudo é evolução. Tem que dar um passo de cada vez, e são muitos. Tem que criar primeiro o ovo pra depois a galinha. Ou seria o contrário? Felizmente esse dilema não existe na computação, primeiro veio o binário (que já é um conceito abstrato), depois o código numérico (que é um nível mais alto), mais tarde o texto com o Assembly e só na década de 50 surgiram as linguagens mais abstratas e próximas do que nós humanos entendemos.

Para mostrar melhor terei que ir mais a fundo, teria que mostrar cada passo. Fica longo demais. Os *links* já ajudam pesquisar mais. Não pode ter preguiça de clicar neles todos aqui, nem na Wikipedia. É, cansa, mas é o único jeito para aprender tudo e entender por completo.

Há uma [pergunta sobre o funcionamento dos processadores modernos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101). Não é tão diferente do início, ainda que tiveram "vários inícios".

Também útil: [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: bigown e OnoSendai muito obrigado pelas respostas, esclareceram bastante coisa. As duas respostas foram ótimas e infelizmente só dá para marcar uma como aceita. Marquei a do @bigown porque achei mais esclarecedora, mas as duas foram ótimas. Só fazendo uma recapitulação para ver se eu entendi. O que evolui na verdade foi a entrada de dados, não é? O assembly foi (inicialmente) apenas para facilitar a escrita dos programas. A entrada de dados era ainda feita manualmente. Somente depois que surgiram os teclados, que o computador passou a ser programado diretamente, certo?

Comment: @MichaelPacheco A entrada de dados ( o programa) é feita manualmente até hoje, só que os dados são em nível mais próximo do que o ser humano entende. A diferença é que antes se entrava inicialmente os bits ao invés de caracteres e que as chaves eram mais rudimentares. Até falo que usamos chaves até hoje, só que é uma chave (tecla) mais fácil de usar e que já considera uma informação mais completa que um bit. São duas coisas diferentes que evoluíram: a entrada de dados, ainda que mudou pouca coisa; e a abstração do código, que eu acho que é o que queria saber, foi binário->mneumônicos->Assembly

Comment: Há duas semanas atrás precisei montar uma apresentação sobre linguagens de programação. Seria excelente se eu tivesse essa sua resposta à mão naquela ocasião, me teria sido muito útil. +1

Answer (score 28):

> Como que alguém conseguiria escrever um código em assembly sendo que não existia editor de textos nem nada?

A resposta é meio longa, porém valerá a pena. Vamos aproveitar para limpar alguns conceitos:

Todo e qualquer valor em um computador eletrônico, seja valvulado ou transistorizado, se resume a presença de sinal (geralmente `1` ou verdadeiro) ou ausência (`0` ou falso).

> Quando fosse preciso trocar o programa, os programadores apenas rearranjavam as válvulas e a máquina continuava a trabalhar [...]

Na verdade válvulas funcionavam como os transístores que lhe sucederam: Seu estado poderia ser alterado por sinais.

Programas, mesmo nos mais modernos computadores, nada mais são do que valores expressos em formato binário que instruem ao processador como outros valores (dados) de acordo com instruções pré-determinadas.

---

Do artigo sobre [programação da Wikipedia em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming#History) (tradução livre):

> [...] programas [para a primeira geração de computadores] tinham que ser meticulosamente informados usando as instruções (operações elementares) da máquina em particular, muitas vezes em notação binária.
>
> Cada modelo de computador utilizava instruções diferentes (linguagem de máquina) para realizar a mesma tarefa.

Computadores como o ENIAC utilizavam tabelas de função - literalmente grandes mapas de bits - para inserir as instruções:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>[Cpl. Irwin Goldstein (foreground) sets the switches on one of ENIAC's function tables at the Moore School of Electrical Engineering. (U.S. Army photo)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC#/media/File:Classic_shot_of_the_ENIAC.jpg)</sup>

O operador então programava o computador ligando e desligando centenas de switches físicos nestes painéis.

Cartões sucederam as tabelas de função, utilizando o mesmo mecanismo: Cada posição do cartão correspondia a um valor verdadeiro/falso.

> Mais tarde, as linguagens de montagem (*assembly*) foram desenvolvidas, permitindo que o programador especificasse cada instrução em um formato de texto, informando abreviaturas para cada código de operação em vez de um número binário, especificando endereços de forma simbólica (por exemplo, `ADD X, TOTAL`).

A primeira versão de Assembly não era realmente texto, apenas um conjunto de mnemônicos de um caracter que agregava várias instruções. Utilizada pelo [EDSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_delay_storage_automatic_calculator#System_software), ela se chamava Ordens Iniciais.

Essas bibliotecas de funções foram se expandindo, com vários mnemônicos cobrindo mais e mais conjuntos de operações.

O primeiro computador com um conjunto de instruções Assembly foi o [IBM 650](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_650#Instruction_set). Utilizando válvulas e cartões perfurados, ele continha um set de 650 instruções - uma combinação de 2 dígitos para operação, 4 para o endereço de memória e 4 para a próxima instrução. Note a similaridade com linguagens Assembly modernas:

```
#      op|data|next
         |addr|instruction

0001 - 00 0001 0000  
0002 - 00 0000 0000
0003 - 10 0001 8003
0004 - 61 0008 0007
0005 - 24 0000 8003
0006 - 01 0000 8000
0007 - 69 0006 0005
0008 - 20 1999 0003
```

Lidas do formato mnemônico, ficavam assim:

```
0004  RSU  61 0008 0007  Reseta o acumulador, subtrai do superior (8003) o valor 2019990003
0007  LD   69 0006 0005  Carrega valor 0100008000 no distribuidor
0005  STD  24 0000 8003  Armazena distribuidor no endereço 0000: Próxima instrução na
                         posição 8003
```

> Introduzir um programa em linguagem assembly é geralmente mais conveniente, mais rápido e menos propenso a erros humanos do que o uso direto de linguagem de máquina, mas porque uma linguagem *assembly* é pouco mais que uma notação diferente para uma linguagem de máquina, quaisquer duas máquinas com conjuntos de instruções diferentes também têm diferentes linguagens *assembly*.

A resposta para sua pergunta então seria: ***Inicialmente diretamente na memória, seguido de cópias de bits de uma mídia externa (cartões, por exemplo)***.

---

Os passos descritos até agora explicam como computadores se tornaram sofisticados o suficiente para processar conjuntos de comandos. Vamos agora à sua segunda pergunta:

> [...] O resultado de uma montagem é outro arquivo no formato texto com 0s e 1s apenas? Ou são impulsos elétricos enviados para a máquina valvulada.

Tudo em um computador são sinais binários via impulsos elétricos, ou representações destes estados. Até mesmo um arquivo texto, onde letras e símbolos são representados por... códigos binários.

No início monitores eram [fileiras de válvulas luminescentes utilizadas para exibir o estado de um bit em particular dentro do computador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_monitor#History). Entretanto, como a tecnologia que dava suporte às televisões da época utilizavam válvulas para exibir imagens, logo a tecnologia foi migrada para o universo dos computadores: Assim nascia o VDU (video display terminal); o primeiro modelo comercial foi o [Datapoint 3300](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datapoint_3300), lançado em 1967.

Outra tecnologia foi absorvida dos teletipos e máquinas de datilografar da época, o teclado. O ENIAC foi o primeiro computador a fazer uso de um, tanto para entrada de dados quando para saída, como impressora.

O casamento das duas tecnologias - onde as instruções mnemônicas podiam ser visualizadas em um monitor, e um teclado que permitia a entrada ágil de instruções - permitiu o avanço dos métodos de programação de dispositivos.

Lembra que arquivos texto são na verdade sequências de códigos binários? Um dos primeiros códigos a ser largamente utilizado foi o [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), criado em 1960 e derivado do código telegráfico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>[ASCII chart from a 1972 printer manual (b1 is the least significant bit).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#/media/File:US-ASCII_code_chart.png)</sup>

Neste formato a letra `A` é representada pelo valor 65, `B` por 66 e assim por diante.

Um primeiro programa, escrito em linguagem de máquina (muito provavelmente utilizando os mnemônicos de operadores), foi criado para permitir que os dados oriundos do teclado fossem alocados em um espaço de memória, no formato de *código-fonte*. Vamos a um exemplo em C:

```
 volatile int x, y;
 int
 main ()
 {
   x = foo (y);
   return 0;
 }
```

Este programa copiava, caracter por caracter, o a entrada de teclado para a memória - sem interpretar seu conteúdo, apenas exibindo-o na tela. Por exemplo, a palavra 'volatile' seria armazenada assim:

```
v 01110110 
o 01101111 
l 01101100 
a 01100001 
t 01110100 
i 01101001 
l 01101100 
e 01100101
```

Extremamente ineficiente, não? Uma outra parte do programa lia estes endereços, *compilando-os*, e os transformava nos mnemônicos utilizados pelo processador.

Nosso exemplo em C ficaria assim:

```
 5  {
 6    x = foo (y);
    0x0000000000400400 <+0>:    mov    0x200c2e(%rip),%eax # 0x601034 <y>
    0x0000000000400417 <+23>:   mov    %eax,0x200c13(%rip) # 0x601030 <x>
 7    return 0;
 8  }
    0x000000000040041d <+29>:   xor    %eax,%eax
    0x000000000040041f <+31>:   retq
    0x0000000000400420 <+32>:   add    %eax,%eax
    0x0000000000400422 <+34>:   jmp    0x400417 <main+23>
```

A representação 0xN é a representação das operações mnemônicas (como `mov`, `xor` e `retq`) da maneira como são vistas pelo processador.

O operador então movia o ponteiro de execução para o resultado compilado, *executando* o código binário.

O resto, como dizem, é história.

Comment: OnoSendai eu acho que a parte que mais importa, a última, deveria ser mais aprofundada.

Comment: @JorgeB. Que tal?

Comment: @OnoSendai muito obrigado pela resposta! Agradeço pela sua dedicação, imagino que deve ter sido bem trabalhoso organizar tanta informação.

Comment: @MichaelPacheco não por isso, é sempre um prazer ajudar. =)