# Como uma Java Virtual Machine escrita em Java funciona?

Tags: java, jvm

Vendo o [Jikes RVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jikes_RVM) eu fiquei curioso para saber como isso funciona (na teoria), mas só achei material em inglês.

Estou correto em assumir que a JVM hoje é feita em C/C++, que por sua vez é feito em Assembler?

Como é possível que uma linguagem se "auto interprete"? Isso já foi feito em outras linguagens?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Primeiro, para fazer um **compilador** da linguagem X escrito ele mesmo na linguagem X, faça isso:

1. Utilizando-se a linguagem Y, codifique e compile um compilador C<sub>1</sub> para a linguagem X, que produza código executável na plataforma P. Compile-o com o compilador K já anteriormente existente da linguagem Y.
2. Utilizando-se a linguagem X, codifique e compile um compilador C<sub>2</sub> para a linguagem X, que produza código executável na plataforma P. Compile-o com o compilador C<sub>1</sub> da linguagem X. Note que isso produzirá um compilador da linguagem X escrito na própria linguagem X.
3. Recompile C<sub>2</sub> usando o próprio C<sub>2</sub>, gerando um compilador C<sub>2b</sub>.
4. Certifique-se que C<sub>2</sub> é idêntico a C<sub>2b</sub> (ou que pelo menos, não haja nenhuma diferença com a qual você se importe). Se não for, ajuste os códigos dos compiladores C<sub>1</sub> e C<sub>2</sub> até ser.
5. Jogue fora C<sub>1</sub>.

Você pode fazer esse processo várias vezes para a partir da linguagem X1, construir a linguagem X2, da X2 construir a X3, etc. É por esse motivo que o javac e o eclipsec, os únicos dois compiladores Java maduros e ativos atualmente, são feitos eles mesmos em Java. Esse processo é chamado de bootstrap.

Entretanto, o caso aqui é com um **interpretador**, e não um compilador. Mas o raciocínio é semelhante. O JikesRVM precisa de um pequeno carregador minimal feito em C para poder começar o processo de bootstrap. Todo o resto que não for essencial para se começar tudo, é feito em Java. A ideia é que tudo o que puder **não** ser feito em C, que seja feito em Java, ficando no C somente aquilo para o qual não há forma alguma de se implementar em Java.

Entretanto, a maioria das JVMs disponíveis ao público têm amplas partes desenvolvidas em C e C++ mesmo, principalmente por questões de desempenho, consumo de memória e criticidade do código. Por outro lado, o JikesRVM não é uma JVM comercial, e portanto é utilizada apenas em nichos específicos, uma vez que o objetivo dela não é competir com as outras JVMs na execução de programas de usuários.

Além disso, esse conceito não é lá muito novo não. LISP é uma linguagem que faz isso desde que foi concebida. Muitos interpretadores de LISP são escritos no próprio LISP, tendo apenas uma pequena parte minimal responsável pelas funcionalidades mais básicas escrita em alguma outra linguagem.

Comment: Eu até entendo uma aplicação que fale "direto" com o SO consiga criar um compilador utilizando ela mesma ou um Java que gere um .class (um programa Java que leia um .java e o compile), mas não consigo visualizar uma Máquina Virtual feita em Java que não precise do JVM.

Comment: Marcus, eu também não via isso, por isso fui atrás de pesquisar. A sacada está no pequeno núcleo em C++. Na verdade é uma JVM híbrida, com partes escritas em C++ e partes em Java (na verdade, todas as JVMs são assim, híbridas de Java com uma linguagem nativa que quase sempre é C++). O único porém é que no caso do JikesRVM, eles secaram a parte do C++ até não conseguir tirar mais nada de lá.

Comment: Retirar o C++ todo seria impossível, pois isso significaria que a execução teria que começar no Java, e que para isso seria necessário uma outra JVM.

Answer (score 14):

Isso se chama [*bootstrapping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping).

## Compiladores

[Linguagens são apenas especificações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101). Ainda que relacionadas, [linguagens e compiladores são coisas diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

[Compiladores e bibliotecas formam o que a especificação manda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101). É óbvio que a primeira implementação da linguagem precisa ser escrita em outra linguagem. Depois é possível usar a própria linguagem para criar uma nova implementação escrita nela mesmo.

Compiladores são algoritmos relativamente básicos, cheio de complexidades específicas, claro. Entra dados de texto, processa, e aí está a complexidade, e gera um dado, possivelmente binário que uma máquina virtual ou física sabe como executar. É só um algoritmo de transformação seguindo regras específicas. Então eles geram um programa que pode ser executado e isso pode ser um compilador, uma máquina virtual, um sistema operacional, qualquer coisa.

Eu até entendo a curiosidade, mas acho estranho que pareça algo muito difícil de alcançar. Acho que o único "segredo" é saber que o primeiro compilador deve ser feito em outra linguagem.

Na verdade algumas linguagens são feitas incrementalmente. Faz-se um compilador que trate o mínimo, e vai adicionando funcionalidade depois. Assim você quase tem um compilador inicial na própria linguagem. Claro que as primeiras interações desse desenvolvimento a linguagem será um pouco diferente do desejado no final, e um pouco limitada.

[Linguagens de programação podem produzir qualquer coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101), então não tem segredo algum uma linguagem produzir um compilador para si próprio, desde que exista uma primeira implementação.

Claro que algumas linguagens não são as mais adequadas para produzir compiladores.

As melhores implementações de Java são realmente escritas em C++. Java, hoje, não parece muito adequada para produzir compiladores. Já foi pior. [Java é compilada e não interpretada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101) em sua base. É possível ter um interpretador.

## Interpretadores

Um interpretador nada mais é que um compilador que no final em vez de gerar um executável, ele já executa o que foi analisado. Um interpretador é um programa executável como outro qualquer. Mas neste caso o compilador gera um *bytecode* e este é que será "interpretado" pela máquina virtual.

Claro que no caso do interpretador executar a si próprio ele precisa ser [reentrante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentr%C3%A2ncia), o que não é simples.

O que eu posso garantir é que tem um trecho de código em outra linguagem, um trecho que justamente faz o *bootstrap* da máquina virtual. Lendo o artigo na Wikipedia, fala disto:

> A small C loader is responsible for loading the boot image at runtime

O compilador, do interpretador, é separado da máquina virtual, mesmo que esteja no mesmo executável. A máquina virtual não interpreta Java, ele interpreta um *bytecode*, e pelo que entendi esse Jikes nem usa o *bytecode* padrão.

Obviamente eu não tenho detalhes desse projeto e não posso afirmar sobre cada especificidade de como ele funciona.

## Mais informações

Compiladores C e C++ são escritos em C++ há bastante tempo. Alguns ainda possuem uma boa parte escrita em C. Alguém pode fazer em Assembly (Assembler não é o nome correto), mas há anos que ninguém seriamente faz isso.

[C# hoje tem seu compilador escrito em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) e funciona melhor do que o original escrito em C++. O *runtime* é escrito basicamente em C++, mas há experimentos em C# com resultados melhorando, mas aquém do desejado.

Já falei sobre isso em [A primeira linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156521/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Pensei em escrever algo assim e já tinha a resposta escrito pela metade, mas há um problema. Ele está falando de um interpretador, e não de um compilador. Com isso, a coisa fica um pouco mais complicada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa porque fica mais complicado?

Comment: Porque você tem que fazer um programa interpretar a si mesmo sem estar rodando em um outro interpretador, que é o que o JikesRVM diz fazer. A parte de não estar rodando em outro interpretador é que complica, de acordo com o site deles "*i.e., its Java code runs on itself without requiring a second virtual machine.*".

Comment: @VictorStafusa não sabia disto, vou ver mais e vou melhorar. Pode responder também se tiver algo que fale especificamente sobre isso. Mas a princípio não vejo problemas também.

Comment: Essa ideia de *bootstrapping* sem precisar de outra VM, é como o roslyn faz, não é?

Comment: @jbueno na verdade não, editei e falei sobre isto. Vão falando aí que eu vou melhorando.

Comment: @bigown Bem, postei a minha resposta adicional.