# Seria preciso ter outra linguagem de programação para se criar o assembler?

Tags: assembly, design-de-linguagem

Seria preciso ter outra linguagem de programação para se criar o assembler? Se sim, qual? Se não, o que poderia fazer para começar?

Sei que conforme os anos, logo após os cartões perfurados, surgiu a linguagem assembly. Mas, a linguagem de programação Assembly e seu compilador Assembler também foi programada com outra linguagem de programação? Se sim, qual seria?

Comment: Obrigada! E pessoal, desculpa pelas premissas erradas. É que quando ia corrigir já tinha enviado rs.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo;

Answer (score 15):

Há premissas erradas na pergunta. Assembly (ênfase no maiúsculo) existe antes dos cartões perfurados que na verdade é só uma entrada de dados. Assembler não é um compilador, embora algumas pessoas acham que sim. Ele até é uma forma de compilador, mas não é completo, por isso é considerado apenas um montador, como o nome diz.

Tem perguntas que ajudam entender melhor isso e sobre a primeira linguagem de programação:

- [Como um computador entende o código binário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101)
- [A primeira linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156521/101)
- [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101)
- [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101)
- [O que caracteriza uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101)
- [O que é assembler?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178804/101)

A linguagem de máquina é o código binário que a máquina entende. Ela até pode ser ser escrita fora da máquina, mas é raro quem faça. Ela não precisa ser transformada.

O Assembly é um texto "compreensível" por humanos. O Assembly existe fora da máquina, depois de entrada no computador precisa de uma transformação, pelo assembler. Há uma relação de 1 para 1 entre o código Assembly e o código de máquina.

O assembler é um mecanismo de tradução do Assembly para o código de máquina, portanto ele é um software. Sendo assim, ele precisa ser desenvolvido em alguma linguagem. O primeiro certamente foi escrito em código de máquina. Daí pra frente foi possível, mas não necessariamente foi feito assim, esse e outros assemblers foram usados para escrever qualquer tipo de software, incluindo compiladores e outros assemblers. Hoje é possível usar uma linguagem de alto nível para escrever um assembler.

Então respondendo estritamente a pergunta feita, sim, hoje em dia é possível escrever um assembler com qualquer linguagem de programação. Na década de 40 foi necessário usar a linguagem de máquina.

Assembly é uma linguagem de programação, portanto ela é apenas uma [especificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101).

[Programe binário aqui](http://s2js.com/altair/sim.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Assembly/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Luana, um programa compilado são códigos em formato suportado pela arquitetura do processador - Os processadores da intel por exemplo seguem a arquitetura CISC - Cada arquitetura tem um conjunto de comandos próprios. Segue um link com os opcodes do processador z80, um bom processador para aprender: [Opcodes z80](http://jgmalcolm.com/z80/opcodes/opcodesN.htm)

Um compilador na verdade, transforma suas linhas de código em uma série de opcodes equivalentes. Já o assembly são os próprios opcodes, por exemplo:

```
ld a, #1800  //Carrega o valor na posição de memória #1800 para o registrador a
adc a, #1802 //Soma o valor em a com o valor na posição #1802
ld #1804, a  // Grava o valor de a na posição #1804 da memória
```

Isto seria equivalente, mais ou menos a `x = y + z;`

O Assembler só seria responsável então por transformar isso em binário.

Espero que tenha respondido sua pergunta de forma clara.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estivesse criando agora um novo processador e não tivesse outra máquina disponível, você teria que escrever o primeiro assembler para ele em código de máquina direto em um disco, fita, cartões ou mesmo memória. E provavelmente, esse assembler teria o mínimo de recursos necessários para você conseguir escrever uma próxima versão com mais recursos em assembly ou em uma linguagem de mais alto nivel.

Como hoje em dia dispomos de diversas linguagens de todos os níveis você pode escolher a linguagem que é mais apropriada para gerar o assembler, e o C costuma ser a primeira melhor opção.

Comment: Se estivesse criando o primeiro computador do mundo não existiria disco, fira, cartões, nem memória. Durante mais de uma década só existiram assemblers e muitos já não eram tão simples assim. A maioria dos assemblers puros ainda são escritos em Assembly e código de máquina.