# Como são criadas as linguagens de programação?

Tags: característica-linguagem

Algumas vezes quando eu programo, me passa pela cabeça que eu estou programando a partir de um programa já que quem interpreta ou compila é um programa. Então eu pensei, como são criadas as linguagens de programação?

- As linguagens de programação são criadas a partir de uma outra linguagem certo? Sendo assim qual linguagem é utilizada geralmente?
- Se não houver uma linguagem X adotada para a criação de uma linguagem de programação, como ela pode ser criada ?
- Se linguagens de programação forem usadas para criar outras linguagens de programação, isso em algum momento não seria ruim para a performance, como por exemplo, criar uma linguagem X com Java ou Ruby que já são um pouquinho lentas ou pesadas?

Eu já li essas outras perguntas que indicaram:

- [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124449/157404)
- [Seria preciso ter outra linguagem de programação para se criar o assembler?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206435/157404)
- [A primeira linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156521/157404)

São perguntas bastante interessantes que tem haver um pouco com o assunto mas ainda não é o que eu quero. A pergunta não é sobre a criação das primeiras linguagens de programação, como um computador funciona ou sobre como é decidido criar uma linguagem.

O que eu quero saber é sobre as linguagens de programação de alto nível mais recentes e as próximas que virão. Quero saber com o que elas são criadas e como disse anteriormente, se isso não causaria algum impacto na performance com o passar do tempo.

Comment: Além da duplicada já indicada, também tem [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156521/112052) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206435/112052) - e todas elas tem respostas com vários outros links complementares

Comment: Eu fechei, mas olhando com mais atenção pode ser que a pergunta não seja exatamente duplicata. Pode ser que a forma feita não ajude ficar claro isso (poderia melhorar, quem sabe considerando já saber sobre a duplicata se o intuito seria outras informações não contempladas nos links colocados)). Poderia mudar algo pra indicar o que é diferente da que já existe, enquanto isso vou esperar se outras pessoas se posicionam. Pode ser que nos outros *links* juntos tenha resposta completa, aí eu coloco como parte da duplicata

Comment: @Maniero eu editei a pergunta e espero ter ficado mais claro. Apenas não sei qual a tag correta utilizar na pergunta.

Comment: Não adianta reabrir é muito ampla, teria que explicar um semestre de compiladores para responder a sua pergunta. @JeanExtreme002 você está precisando fazer uma faculdade de ciência da computação você chegou, ou está chegando, no limite que dá para aprender sozinho.