# O que são esses registradores de propósito específicos?

Tags: arquitetura-computadores

Estou acompanhando um [livro sobre Arquitetura de Computadores](http://producao.virtual.ufpb.br/books/edusantana/introducao-a-arquitetura-de-computadores-livro/livro/livro.pdf) e estou na parte de registradores, mas não contém nenhum exemplo prático de como funciona os

> **Registradores de Propósito Específico**.
>
> Entre eles estão:
>
> **PC** (**Program Control**) -> *Possui o endereço e busca a próxima instrução a ser buscada*
>
> **IR** (**Instruction Register**) *Guarda a Instrução e passa para o UCD*
>
> **MAR** (**Memory Adress Register**) *Trabalha quando o dado está na memória e não no registrador*
>
> **MBR** (**Memory Buffer Register**, alias isso tem alguma relação com o `buffer` que vemos em programação?) *Resposta da Memória é gravada
>   em MBR*

Como esses registradores acima funcionam quando estamos codificando?

Os **registradores de propósito geral** são o que guardamos variáveis então o exemplo claro já vem próximo a minha mente, porém os de propósito geral a abordagem é bem diferente...

```
var x = 10 //Seria isso?
```

Comment: Na memória são armazenados esses tipos de dados: 4(curt) ou 8(long) bytes,float,double,array of bytes,bits,string. Pela variável que você deu exemplo é 4 bytes.

Comment: Desculpa pela ignorância, mas não entendi realmente ao que se refere na pergunta...

Comment: Eu falei sobre tipo de dados da variável.

Comment: Cada arquitetura de CI implementa os registradores de maneira diferente. No livro ele está explicando de maneira genérica. E não, as variáveis do seu programa em C não são armazenadas nos registradores de propósito geral, elas são armazenadas na RAM, porém no caminho da entrada até o armazenamento em RAM certamente a informação trafegará por registradores. Sim registradores tem funcionamento análogo a variáveis, porém o escopo de uso deles é intrínseco e restrito a micro operações que são os blocos formadores das instruções das linguagens de programação.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não sabia como funciona todo esse processo, achava que iria direto para o registrador (coisa bem estranha, pois aprendi desde cedo que as coisas iriam para memória RAM), pois não fala nada sobre RAM (até o capítulo onde li e fiquei na dúvida). Mesmo assim, agradeço pela explicação. Sobre as arquiteturas de CI tem algum site informando as mais famosas ou todas?

Comment: Acho que o quê você está procurando são os manuais dos fabricantes. [http://home.ifi.uio.no/...IA32Doc/](http://home.ifi.uio.no/griff/INF5063/IA32Doc/) Esses são todos os manuais da arquitetura IA-32(x86), estão em inglês e estão disponíveis gratuitamente no site da Intel, só que aquilo é uma zona e iria me tomar um bom tempo  para fazer a consulta, então preferi passar esse link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu começaria lendo [Como um computador entende o código binário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101).

**PC** - é o registrador usado para determinar em que endereço ele deve executar em seguida.  Toda instrução executada faz ele se mover para a próxima instrução. Em processadores RISC é fácil porque todas instruções possuem o mesmo tamanho e o incremento é tranquilo, em processadores CISC é preciso achar o tamanho em uma tabela interna e incrementar aquilo. Ele só aponta para regiões da memória que tenha código e não dados. Ele pode ser manipulado por um código quando existe algum *branch* no seu código, seja por um `if`, `while` ou `goto` simples, ou seja, seu código pode manipulá-lo.

**IR** - geralmente de uso mais interno tem a instrução para ser executada, é uma espécie de cache e só costuma estar presente em processadores RISC que executa uma instrução em vários ciclos e precisa de um controle maior do que está ocorrendo.

**MAR** - também costuma ser interno e indica onde está um dado para ser transferido de ou para o processador. Ele costuma ser necessário para operações de transporte de dados. Ele costuma ser usado quando vai acessar ou atribuir valores para uma variável, como mostrado na pergunta.

**MBR** - também costuma ser interno e usado como uma espécie de cache para armazenar o dado que que será transferido, isto é útil porque o processador pode estar executando outra instrução enquanto essa transferência ocorre.

Somente o PC é útil para quem está programando, e mesmo assim se estiver usando Assembly.

Variáveis são padrões de projeto para acesso à endereços que pode ser de memória RAM ou de um registrador (ao contrário do que diz a outra resposta). É extremamente comum que um programador Assembly use registradores como suas variáveis e os compiladores minimamente bons colocam o máximo que podem de variáveis locais e parâmetros em registradores.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ótima resposta, mas tudo isso na hora que estamos programando, saber disso faz diferença nos dias atuais? Você disse "Somente o PC é útil para quem está programando, e mesmo assim se estiver usando Assembly." fora desse contexto então não é de tão grande utilidade assim saber desse assunto. Lamento pela ignorância, estou aprendendo agora e estou focado nisso.

Comment: Em programação normal não, mas é bom ter entendimento básico do que acontece na máquina quando está programando, até pra saber o que ocorre de fato naquele código. É importante pra entender o todo. Isso é um passo para construir o conhecimento, algo que a maiores das pessoas não sabe mais fazer e não se importam em saber apenas o sufciente pra ver o resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, cada um desses registradores tem um propósito no gerenciamento da memória, na descrição de cada um já diz o que são, para ver na prática você consegue encontrar imagens ilustrativas na internet, para trabalhar diretamente com eles, você precisa saber como cada tipo de arquitetura(ex:MIPS,x86)  funcionam.

Com linguagem Assembly ou alguma que tenha acesso privilegiado a memória, você vai conseguir manipular esses registradores.

Exemplo de um código em Assembly, usando registradores de dados e processamento:

```
section .text

       global _start     ;must be declared for linker (gcc)

    _start:          ;tell linker entry point
       mov  edx,len  ;message length
       mov  ecx,msg  ;message to write
       mov  ebx,1    ;file descriptor (stdout)
       mov  eax,4    ;system call number (sys_write)
       int  0x80     ;call kernel

       mov  edx,9    ;message length
       mov  ecx,s2   ;message to write
       mov  ebx,1    ;file descriptor (stdout)
       mov  eax,4    ;system call number (sys_write)
       int  0x80     ;call kernel

       mov  eax,1    ;system call number (sys_exit)
       int  0x80     ;call kernel

    section .data
    msg db 'Displaying 9 stars',0xa ;a message
    len equ $ - msg  ;length of message
    s2 times 9 db '*'
```

eax, edx, ecx, etc; são registradores.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela explicação e pelo código demonstrativo, estou iniciando nessa parte de arquitetura para saber o que estarei fazendo mais para frente ao construir meus códigos, e como melhorar etc... Além do mais, gosto de saber como funciona de baixo dos panos.